# Spring Data Rest Many to many tree projection mapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-rest

I have an entity called ContentPath, with may have a parent of the same type, and sons of the same type, represented with something like:

```
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME", length = 50)
    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    private String description;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="CONTENT_PATH_ID")
    public ContentPath contentPath;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="contentPath")
    public Set<ContentPath> contentPaths;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "ACTIVITY_CONTENT_PATH",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "CONTENT_PATH_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "ACTIVITY_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")})
    private Set<Activity> activities;
```

I have my ContentPathRepository, which exposes it as an API.

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "contentPaths", path = "contentPaths", excerptProjection = ContentPathProjection.class)
public interface ContentPathRestRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<ContentPath, Long> {

}
```

and my projection, which should format correctly my object.

```
@Projection(name = "contentPathProjection", types = ContentPath.class)
public interface ContentPathProjection {
    Long getId();
    String getName();
    Set<ContentPath> getContentPaths();
}
```

I was expecting to get a list of ContentPaths, which have their ContentPaths inside, and I got success, but it is not bringing IDs, it is bringing Name and Description only, and it is very weird because my projection doesn't have the Description.

Current response:

```
"name": "BOOK 1",
"id": 1,
"contentPaths": [
    {
        "name": "UNIT 1",
        "description": "UNIT 1 description"
    },
    {
        "name": "UNIT 2",
        "description": "UNIT 2 description"
    }
]
```

Why is it happening? How fix it?

Comment: do you have public getter for `ContentPath.id` ?

Comment: Yes.  `public Long getId() {return id;}`

But the weird thing is also it is returning a description, but I don't have a description in my projection.

Comment: And it is also returning the ID for the first level, but not for the second.

Comment: @LuizMitidiero Don't forget to accept/upvote answers that helped you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a normal behavior of SDR. It don't show `id` by default. To turn this on just register a bean like this:

```
@Bean
public RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter repositoryRestConfigurerAdapter() {
    return new RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
            config.exposeIdsFor(ContentPath.class);
            super.configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(config);
        }
    };
}
```

About `description` - you have this field:

```
@Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
private String description;
```

Comment: It solved the problem, but I would like to understand why? How can I expose the other fields, like relationships?

Comment: @LuizMitidiero look at: https://spring.io/understanding/HATEOAS and https://speakerdeck.com/olivergierke/spring-data-rest-repositories-meet-hypermedia

Comment: @LuizMitidiero ...and this: https://speakerdeck.com/olivergierke/hypermedia-apis-with-spring-5